# King's Indian Defense - When to play 6...c5 or 6...e5

Tags: opening, kings-indian

I'm a casual player who enjoys playing the King's Indian Defense as Black, but I don't fully understand yet when it is better to play `6...e5` or `6...c5`. These are my main doubts:

- What are the aims and differences about playing one move instead of the other?
- In which conditions (such as position of opponent's pieces) should I play `6...c5` instead of the more characteristic `6...e5`?

I've looked at this very interesting [question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/16167/why-6-e5-in-kings-indian) about the aims of playing `6...e5`, but it does not mention anything about the difference between the two aforementioned moves.

Any extra insight or suggestion is of course more than welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a KID expert, but Joe Gallagher GM is, so I'll quote him from "Starting out: The King's Indian":

> "If you are going to play the King's Indian with Black you may be a
>   little confused as to whether you should aim for ... c7-c5 or ...
>   e7-e5. I tend to adhere to the following rule:
>
> Play ... e7-e5 except when White develops his queen bishop early. Then
>   it's time to start thinking (just thinking mind you) about ... c7-c5.
>   The move ... c7-c5 is likely to prise open the long diagonal (after
>   ... e7-e5 it usually becomes totally blocked) and the absence of the
>   white bishop from the queenside means the dark squares there (such as
>   b2) may become vulnerable to pressure from the g7 bishop"

Comment: ..c5 is often followed by ..b5 for a Benko-like setup.

Comment: Or a Modern Benoni structure after a subsequent d5 e6 something exd cxd

Comment: @IanBush I like it as a general principle, and thank you for pointing me to Gallagher's book, maybe I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Just as a side note, I've looked at what has been played by Grandmasters after moving the dark-squared bishop in all the possible squares, and only after `6. Be3` (which enters the _Larsen variation_) the move `6...e5` is the most popular one. This could be an exception to Gallagher's general suggestion.

Comment: Well Be3 often stops c5 as a viable move as after it c5 just drops a pawn for Black ... But see the Saemisch Gambit